# onclick/onchange event for radio button deselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if anyone knew how to solve an issue I've been raking my brain over all day, and get some fresh thinking into it. The situation is as follows, I need to make a form with mostly radio button style questions, styled as image buttons. The part at which I'm stuck on is trying to get the image to revert back after the radio button is de-selected, either through the onclick or onchange event.

Is there any workaround or method of getting an event to fire after a radio button is de-selected? Any input to solve this problem would be welcome. An example question goes as follows:

```
<input type="radio" id="switch" onclick="changeImage()" name="radiogroup" style="visibility: hidden;">
<img id="Image1" src="normal.png" onclick="changeImage()">


<script>
  function changeImage() {
      var image = document.getElementById('Image1');
      if (image.src.match("normalb")) {
          image.src = "normal.png";
          var x = document.getElementById("switch");
      x.checked = false;
      } else {
          image.src = "normalb.png";
          var x = document.getElementById("switch");
      x.checked = true;
      }
  }
</script>

<input type="radio" id="switch2" onclick="changeImage2()" name="radiogroup" style="visibility: hidden;">
<img id="Image2" src="dry.png" onclick="changeImage2()">


<script>
  function changeImage2() {
      var image = document.getElementById('Image2');
      if (image.src.match("dryb")) {
          image.src = "dry.png";
          var x = document.getElementById("switch2");
      x.checked = false;
      } else {
          image.src = "dryb.png";
          var x = document.getElementById("switch2");
      x.checked = true;
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: you can't de-select a radio button. radio button usually works in groups, intercepted by the name attribute. It can be toggled with another option, but once its selected, i can't be unselected.

Comment: You don't even need javascript. You can use css to change the background url of an element depending on it's state. Example: `input[type=radio]:checked { background: url('checked.png'); }` and `input[type=radio] { background: url('unchecked.png'); }`

Comment: Although... it's unclear exactly what you're looking for. When you talk about a button being deselected, do you mean when the user chooses another button in the same radio group? Or do you mean when they have selected an button and moved on to another radio group?

Comment: I tried your code and clicking on it does correctly toggle between normal.png and normalb.png as well as between dry.png and dryb.png. So to me the image is indeed reverting back. Is there something else that is not working?